# toUpper/toLower in mips

Tags: assembly, character, mips

I need to write a program using mips that will take a string and switch all the uppercase letters to lower case and the lowercase letters to uppercase. My instinct is to write if statements using the letter numerical values but I was wondering if there was a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is definitely a better way of doing this! The ASCII values of corresponding upper and lower case alphabetical characters all differ by exactly `0x20`. For instance, `'A' = 0x41` and `'a' = 0x61`. Basically, the sixth bit is set for lower case characters, and cleared for upper case.

The simplest implementation uses a bit-bashing trick - if you can identify that a character is a letter, you can upcase it using:

```
ch &= ~0x20;
```

Or downcase it with:

```
ch |= 0x20;
```

Remember, this won't work for anything other than alphabetic ASCII characters. You can check whether a character matches that with something like `(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')`.

---

Another approach which avoids `if` entirely would be to build a 256-entry table consisting of the intended output for each character, and indexing into that for each character. It may be *slightly* more efficient, depending on your processor, but at the expense of being a little more annoying to write out (or generate).

Comment: The question was if there was a better way to do this than using if statements.

Comment: And the answer is yes - there are indeed better ways to do this than 52 if statements (one for each letter in each case), and this is one of them!

Comment: But this still requires if statements ie: `(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')`. I don't think the OP was thinking of using `if char == a, if char == b, etc`

Comment: They didn't mention anything else, so I'm assuming that *is* what they were planning to do. Nevertheless, added a branchless alternative.

Comment: I don't think there is much basis to suggest that your "ifless" alternative is faster.

Comment: Like I said, it depends heavily on the processor. If your processor absolutely hates branches, a table will perform better. If your processor has a tiny cache, logic will perform better. If neither is the case, it's a toss-up.

Comment: You can also implement `tolower` as `return ((unsigned)(c) - 'A' < 26) ? c | 32 : c;`, which avoids one of the branches by using unsigned underflow instead.